# Fluent Nhibernate: how to map bidirectional relationship

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping, bidirectional-relation

I'm trying to map the following but not sure if it is at all possible with the current nHibernate/fluent nHibernate so any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Basically I've got the following 2 classes

```
public class Venue
{
    public virtual int ID {get;set;}
    public virtual VenueDetail CurrentDetails {get; set;}
    public virtual IEnumerable<VenueDetail> PreviousDetails {get; set;}
}

public class VenueDetail
{
    public virtual int ID {get;set;}
    public virtual string Description {get;set;}
    public virtual Venue Venue {get;set;}
}
```

Is there a way to effectively map the above relationship? My Venue table has a foreign key to the VenueDetail for the CurrentVenueDetails property, at the same time my VenueDetail also has a foreign key back to the Venue table for the Venue property.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

[It is pretty much all described here for you.](https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/wiki/Fluent-mapping)

```
public class VenueDetailMap : ClassMap<VenueDetail>
{
    ....
    //Reference the One side of the OneToMany
    Reference(x => x.Venue);
    ....
}

public class VenueMap : ClassMap<Venue>
{
    ....
    //Declare this is the many side
    HasMany(x => x.PreviousDetails);
    // We are referencing another entity here
    References( x => x.CurrentDetails);
    ....
}
```